# How to get code coverage in an if statement

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have 75% coverage. There isn't code coverage for this part of the code

```
if (rsp.Role__c <> Null && rsp.Role__c <> 'Other')
            {
                trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+rsp.Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');                    
            }
```

What do I need to add in order to get to that code?

This is my trigger code

```
trigger trgr_Check_Duplicate_Roles on Key_Staff_People__c (before insert,before update) {


    for (Key_Staff_People__c rsp: Trigger.new) 
        {
            List <Key_Staff_People__c> rcrd = [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c 
                                                  WHERE Contact__c = :rsp.Contact__c
                                                 AND Role__c = :rsp.Role__c ];        


            if (rcrd.size() > 0)
            {
                if (rsp.Role__c <> Null && rsp.Role__c <> 'Other')
                {
                    trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+rsp.Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is the test class

```
@isTest 
public class trgr_Check_Duplicate_Roles_Test {
    @testSetup static void test_DataSetup() 
    {

        Id acctRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Account' AND Name='FIGS Federation Account' LIMIT 1].ID;
        Id contactRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Contact' AND Name='Contact' LIMIT 1].ID;

        List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        List<Key_Staff_People__c> kpList = new List<Key_Staff_People__c>();

           Account a1 = new Account(Name='AccountTest1',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId); 
           Account a2 = new Account(Name='AccountTest2',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId);  
           Account a3 = new Account(Name='AccountTest3',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId);    
           acctList.add(a1);
           acctList.add(a2);
           acctList.add(a3);
           insert acctList;

           Contact c1 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest1',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[0].id);
           Contact c2 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest2',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[1].id); 
           Contact c3 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest3',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[2].id);  
           contactList.add(c1);
           contactList.add(c2);
           contactList.add(c3);
           insert contactList;


           Key_Staff_People__c bm = new Key_Staff_People__c(Contact__c = c1.id, First_Name__c='FName1', Last_Name__c='LName1',role__c = 'Relationship Manager');
           Key_Staff_People__c bm2 = new Key_Staff_People__c(Contact__c = c2.id,First_Name__c='FName2', Last_Name__c='LName2',role__c = 'Relationship Manager');
           Key_Staff_People__c bm3 = new Key_Staff_People__c(Contact__c = c3.id,First_Name__c='FName3', Last_Name__c='LName3',role__c = 'Other');        

           // Insert 
            insert bm;
            insert bm2; 
            insert bm3;

    }

    static testMethod void unitTest () {
        Test.startTest();


        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to create Key_Staff_People__c with same role and contact .

Comment: I put this            Key_Staff_People__c bm = new Key_Staff_People__c(Contact__c = c1.id, First_Name__c='FName1', Last_Name__c='LName1',role__c = 'Relationship Manager'); after test.starttest() but I get an error that it doesn't know what c1.id is.  Where do I put it?

Answer (score 0):

What you must do is create a record that will acomplish the conditions to get the error. In this case

> rsp.Role__c <> Null && rsp.Role__c <> 'Other'

When you're about to do the inserts on the test class put it between a try catch block. On the catch you have to put this:

```
Catch (Exception e) {
   if(e.getMessage()!= PUT HERE THE ERROR MESSAGE YOU WILL GENERATE WITH THE .addError) throw e;
}
```

This way you're actually only throwing an exception if its due to another problem than the one you're actually forcing to happen.